# Getting Error Invalid Binding Path in SIlverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

I have an class say class A :

```
[DataContract]
public class A
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

I am inheriting class A in class B :

```
[DataContract]
public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        Name = "Me"
    }
}
```

And in UI section I bind an object of class B to some control and i set the binding of this control as below :

```
//This code throws an error :Invalid Error

Binding = new Binding{Path = new PropertyPath(objectB.Name),Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay}
```

Edit :
   The value of that property is Guid . So is the "-" in Guid causing the error ?

Answer (score 0):

```
new PropertyPath(objectB.Name)
```

should be

```
new PropertyPath("Name")
```

and set

```
Source = objectB
```

So, it should be:

```
Binding = new Binding
          { 
              Source = objectB, 
              Path = new PropertyPath("Name"),
              Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
          }
```